# How to calculate $ \int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn^2(u,k)\;du$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

How to calculate $$ \int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn(u,k)^2\;du?$$ Where $dn$ is the Jacobi Elliptical function dnoidal and $k \in (0,1)$ is the modulus. I know from the Fórmula $(110.07)$ of [1] (see page 10) that
$$ \int_{0}^{K(k)} dn(u,k)^2\;du=E(k),$$
where $E$ is the normal elliptic integral of the second kind complete. For this I can conclude that
$$ \int_{0}^{2K(k)} dn(u,k)^2\;du=2E(k)?$$

[[1]](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Cr_3CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) P. F. Byrd. M. D. Friedman. Hand Book of Elliptical Integrals for Engineers and Scientis. Springer-Verlag New York Heidelberg Berlim, $1971$.

Comment: Use $\int_{0}^{2a}f(x)\,dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$ if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$ and then your answer is correct.

Comment: And in this case, $dn(2K(k)-x)=dn(x)$ because $2K(k)$ is the period and $dn$ is even. Right?

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can the same reasoning be used for $\int_{0}^{4K(k)} cn(u,k)^2\;du=4\cdot \int_{0}^{K(k)} cn(u,k)^2\;du$?

Comment: Yes the same logic applies but in two steps. First you move form $4K$ to $2K$ and then from $2K$ to $K$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you help in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752485/evaluate-int-0k-textsn4uk-textdu)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know much about these functions but I believe that it is not necessarily true since:
$$I=\int_0^{2K(k)}dn(u,k)^2du$$
$v=u/2$ then $du=2dv$ and our integral becomes:
$$I=2\int_0^{K(k)}dn(2v,k)^2dv$$
and this term of $2v$ rather than $v$ could change the value of the integral depending on what this $dn$ function is

Comment: But it may be that for some property of the $dn$ function what I said is worth.

Comment: yes potentially, have you tried to prove it?

Comment: I tried, but I could not.

Comment: I believe that is true since $dn$ is periodic (with period $2K(k)$) and positive.

Comment: I considered it answered due to the comments of the Paramanand Singh above.